# Error with shared libraries running Salome-Meca

Tags: software-installation, python, dependencies, shared-library, qt5

Recently, I installed the latest version of the salome-meca software, obtained from here:

https://www.code-aster.org/spip.php?article303

After installed it, I try to run it going into the folder `~/salome_meca/appli_V2019_univ` and executing `./salome` but I got the following error:

```
pablo@pablo-H110M-A:~/salome_meca/appli_V2019_univ$ ./salome
runSalome running on pablo-H110M-A
Searching for a free port for naming service: 2813 - OK
Searching Naming Service  + found in 0.1 seconds 
SALOME_Session_Server: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Help.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pablo/salome_meca/V2019_univ/modules/KERNEL_V9_3_0/bin/salome/orbmodule.py", line 172, in waitNSPID
    os.kill(thePID,0)
ProcessLookupError: [Errno 3] No such process

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pablo/salome_meca/appli_V2019_univ/bin/salome/runSalome.py", line 633, in useSalome
    clt = startSalome(args, modules_list, modules_root_dir)
  File "/home/pablo/salome_meca/appli_V2019_univ/bin/salome/runSalome.py", line 578, in startSalome
    session=clt.waitNSPID("/Kernel/Session",mySessionServ.PID,SALOME.Session)
  File "/home/pablo/salome_meca/V2019_univ/modules/KERNEL_V9_3_0/bin/salome/orbmodule.py", line 174, in waitNSPID
    raise RuntimeError("Process %d for %s not found" % (thePID,theName))
RuntimeError: Process 18072 for /Kernel/Session not found
Searching /Kernel/Session in Naming Service  

--- Error during Salome launch ---
```

I think that I have a problem with Qt5 library, but before doing anything I prefer to ask how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The [initial error](https://askubuntu.com/q/1188311/22949) occurred because `libQt5Help.so.5` was not found. The `libqt5help5` package [provides this file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libQt5Help.so.5&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any). I had hoped installing that package may be sufficient to solve the problem, and for some readers of this post, it might:

```bash
sudo apt install libqt5help5
```

However, sometimes the specific package you're looking for is one of many packages you need, and is often installed as a dependency of something that provides more general functionality. Running `apt rdepends package` sometimes helps in figuring this out. The output of `apt rdepends libqt5help5` shows `python-pyqt5` and `python3-pyqt5`. Since the error messages you're getting are from Python, and this software appears to be from 2019, I would proceed by installing `python3-pyqt5` instead:

```
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5
```

***I was mistaken in my previous belief that Salome-Meca used Python 2. My apologies!***

I have not found specific advice in the documentation for Salome-Meca. So that is a reasonable place to start. On my system, I was able to overcome error messages about missing libraries using:

```
sudo apt install qtcreator net-tools libqt5opengl5 libnlopt0
```

Installing `qtcreator` is a kitchen-sink approach to getting Qt libraries. It installs way more than is likely to be necessary--about a gigabyte on my system--and if I find a better way to install what is needed, I'll try to update this with that information.

After I did that, it still wouldn't start. I got [errors like those shown here](https://www.code-aster.org/forum2/viewtopic.php?id=24475), of the form:

```
SALOME_Session_Server: /home/ek/salome_meca/V2019_univ/prerequisites/debianForSalome/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so.1)
SALOME_Session_Server: /home/ek/salome_meca/V2019_univ/prerequisites/debianForSalome/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Xml.so.5)
SALOME_Session_Server: /home/ek/salome_meca/V2019_univ/prerequisites/debianForSalome/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5)
```

...and so on.

I was able to solve (or, in any case, work around) that problem by making Salome-Meca use my system-provided version of `libstdc++.so.6` rather than the version it ships. I did this with `LD_PRELOAD`:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 ./salome
```

When I run Salome Meca that way, it starts successfully:

[image: screenshot of the Salome-Meca graphical interface]

I suspect that [your errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188311/error-running-salome-meca/1188316#comment1986542_1188316) about not having correct library versions available *may* be solvable by installing `qtcreator`, using `LD_PRELOAD` to specify your `libstdc++.so.6`, or both. (I'm not really sure quite what [those errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188311/error-running-salome-meca/1188316#comment1986542_1188316) said, though, and I recommend you update your question with them, whether or not this works.)

Note that if you use `LD_PRELOAD` but you're not running a PC or Mac with a 64-bit Intel or AMD processor, then the path you write after `=` will be different from mine. For example, if you're using a 32-bit system, or an ARM system (of any word size), then your architecture isn't amd64. You can search for `libstdc++.so.6` to find the appropriate path.

Comment: @PabloBascuñan I've managed to download Salome-Meca from the official site (I'd been having trouble with this initially) and I'm working on trying to get it to work. I've found it actually uses Python 2 rather than Python 3. Does installing the `python-pyqt5` package help, or otherwise change the error messages?

Comment: I tried installing python-pyqt5 but the error output is too long to show you here. This is an extraction of the error:



Searching /Kernel/Session in Naming Service  +SALOME_Session_Server: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by SALOME_Session_Server)
SALOME_Session_Server: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.9' not found (required by SALOME_Session_Server)
SALOME_Session_Server: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by SALOME_Session_Server)

Comment: @PabloBascuñan Do you get that output when you install `python-pyqt5`, or after installing it when you run `./salome`? (Unfortunately, the only machine I have available to test this on right now is slow and has no GUI installed, so it's actually missing quite a bit of things that you're unlikely to be missing.)

Comment: It happens after I tried to run ./salome.

Comment: @PabloBascuñan Is the `libqt5core5a` package installed?

Comment: Yes. I'ts installed. 
...
pablo@pablo-H110M-A:~/salome_meca/appli_V2018.0.1_public$ sudo apt-get install libqt5core5a
[sudo] password for pablo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqt5core5a is already the newest version (5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.

Comment: @PabloBascuñan I got it working, and I think what I found may help you, but the errors you encountered and the errors I encountered weren't all the same, so I am not sure. I've edited this answer with details. Whether or not the procedure I've given helps, I do recommend that you edit your answer with full details of what you've tried so farand what happened, including full error messages. (I'm willing to edit information into your answer myself, but I don't have the full details of your error messages that were too long to put in comments, and my own errors were, I think, somewhat different.)

Comment: Sorry I'm at work right now. I going to check your answer later, at home.